# How can i test this method RSpec

Tags: ruby, recursion, rspec

I have this method - choose_option
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5nxd.png)

and this help methods
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4zYj.png)

Question, how can i test and take green light simpelcov.

```
allow(adapter).to receive(:gets).and_return('my_guess')
except(adapter).to receive(:adapter_my_guess)
```

But this don' work
Error:

```
expected: 1 time with any arguments
received: 2 times
```

Because my wrapper all time call choose_option seems like recursion

```
def adapter_my_guess(guess)
  @game.instance_variable_set(:@secret_code, %w[1 2 3 4])
  if @game.attempts.positive?
     puts show_guess_result(@game.my_guess(guess))
  else
     puts I18n.t(:lose_game, secret_code: @game.instance_variable_get(:@secret_code))
  end
end

def wrapper(method_for_wrap)
  puts method_for_wrap
  @game.win == false ? choose_option : Finishe.new(@game, @statistics).finishe
end

def choose_option
  option = input(I18n.t(:start_game_options, option1: OPTION_1, option2: OPTION_2, exit: EXIT))
  case option
  when OPTION_1 then wrapper(adapter_my_guess(input(I18n.t(:puts_guess, exit: OR_EXIT))))
  when OPTION_2 then wrapper(adapter_give_hints)
  else
    raise(StandardError, WRONG_OPTION)
  end
rescue StandardError => e
  puts e
  choose_option
```

end

Comment: Code in images is hard to work with. Would you paste your code into the question, please?

Comment: I need only test all case in adapter_my_guess

Comment: You're not testing the code in `adapter_my_guess` because `except(adapter).to receive(:adapter_my_guess)` is mocking it. Can we see your test?

Comment: Oh sorry i need test all case in choose_option, for_adapter game i have test, sry.

Answer (score 1):

`except(adapter).to receive(:adapter_my_guess)` says `adapter` will receive one and only one call to `adapter_my_guess`. It's received two.

If that is correct, [change your expectation to expect more calls](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-11/docs/setting-constraints/receive-counts) by adding `at_least(1).time`.

If that is not correct, we'd need to know more about your code and test.

---

Some notes...

Do not use `instance_variable_get` and `instance_variable_set` in production code. Grabbing at other object's internal variables tangles up the code and makes it hard to change the object without unforeseen consequences. Make `secret_code` a proper [accessor method](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/11/attr_accessor/).

`choose_option` does three things. It gets the option, it interprets the option, and it decides if it needs to get the option again. Split it into three methods, one to get the option, one to interpret the option, and one to put them together. That will be more flexible and easier to test.

Catching every StandardError is too broad. With the methods split, the option is an argument to a method. You can change the exception to be a more specific [ArgumentError](https://ruby-doc.org/core/ArgumentError.html).

```
def get_option
  input(I18n.t(:start_game_options, option1: OPTION_1, option2: OPTION_2, exit: EXIT))
end

def do_option(option)
  case option
  when OPTION_1 then wrapper(adapter_my_guess(input(I18n.t(:puts_guess, exit: OR_EXIT))))
  when OPTION_2 then wrapper(adapter_give_hints)
  else
    raise(ArgumentError, WRONG_OPTION)
  end
end

def choose_option
  do_option(get_option)
rescue ArgumentError
  choose_option
end
```

Now each can be unit tested without having to mock the whole process. For example, all we need to test in `choose_option` is whether it gets an option, tries to do something with it, and retries.

```
describe '#choose_option' do
  context 'with a good option' do
    it 'gets and does the option once' do
      option = double

      expect(adapter).to receive(:get_option)
        .and_return(option)
      expect(adapter).to receive(:do_option)
        .with(double)

      adapter.choose_option
    end
  end

  context 'with a bad option' do
    it 'gets and does the option again' do
      good_option = double
      bad_option = double

      # This will raise an ArgumentError.
      expect(adapter).to receive(:do_option)
        .with(bad_option)
        .and_call_original

      # This will not.
      expect(adapter).to receive(:do_option)
        .with(good_option)

      # First use the bad option, then the good one.
      expect(adapter).to receive(:get_option)
        .and_return(bad_option, good_option)

      adapter.choose_option
    end
  end    
end
```

We don't need to know what `do_option` nor `get_option` does to test `choose_option`, they can be totally mocked. `do_option` and `get_option` can be unit tested separately.

```
describe '#do_option' do
  subject { adapter.do_option(option) }

  context 'with option 1' do
    let(:option) { described_class.OPTION_1 }

    it 'guesses' do
      expect(adapter).to receive(:adapter_my_guess)
      subject
    end
  end

  context 'with option 2' do
    let(:option) { described_class.OPTION_2 }

    it 'gives hints' do
      expect(adapter).to receive(:adapter_give_hints)
      subject
    end
  end

  context 'with the wrong option' do
    let(:option) { "basset hounds got long ears" }

    it 'raises' do
      expect { subject }.to raise_error(ArgumentError)
    end
  end
end
```

That's the basic approach.

Comment: Yes but when i change once or twice or at_least etc . My received up to, because : when choose_option gets -> def wraper puts(method wich user input) -> and re-call choose_option

Comment: when user input exit or user win game => choose_option off

Comment: `choose_option` does too much. See my edits about how to break it up.

Comment: @Smile And I've added an example how to test *only* the option handling.

Comment: but trouble in wrapper, chooise_option take input my_guess then wrapper puts my_guess (adapter_for_my_guess) and call chooise_wrapper and its do infinity if attempts > 0 or input not 'exit' @Schwern

Comment: @Smile Sorry, I can't follow what you mean.